# How to use js library with define() with js libraries as ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, requirejs, es6-modules

I am translating our part of a javascript module from `jquery`/`requirejs` to `vanilla js`/`ES6 modules`. Most of the libraries used has `ES6 modules` alternatives. One has no meaningful alternative so it still uses `define()` as its root function.

I have replaced `define()` in our code with `import xx from '/node_modules/yy/zz.js'` but trying to load the legacy library this way reports
`'/node_modules/yy/zz.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`.

I am a little bit noob at this. I have found there are loaders like `systemjs` or `webpack` but I was unable to understand from the docs nor from the questions/answers I found whether they are the right ones nor how to set up them to our scenario (import `define()`-based libraries from an `ES6 modules`-based code).

How do you recommend to handle this? What should I put where?

PS: On production, I would like to have the scripts including the libraries minified and bundled (as long as it makes sense). What kind of middleware will be used is not stoned yet, please suggest one. The whole service will be most probably served by ASP.NET Core. We use [BundleMinifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) on other projects.

PS: The project uses `yarn`'s `package.json` to define and install dependencies.

Comment: Have you also added `export` declarations when replacing `define()` calls?

Comment: Yes, I have added export to our code. However, I cannot easily do the replacement in the third-party library.